# firebase deploy from outside functions folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, package.json, firebase-cli

I have a workspace structured as such, where 'app' would normally be the 'functions' folder on `firebase init`

```js
server
--- app
------ controllers
------ middleware
------ db.js
------ index.js //where I export the firebase endpoint
------ router.js
------ serve.js //the express app
--- dist
--- node_modules
--- firebase.json
--- package.json
```

I have no trouble running `firebase serve` from the root to serve the functions locally, but `firebase deploy` requires me to place both the package.json file and the `./dist` folder in `app`.

Is there a way to deploy from the root, without placing the package.json and `./dist` folder in app?

My package.json file:

```js
{
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "rm -rf dist && babel ./app/ -d ./dist && mkdir dist/private && cp app/private/conf.json dist/private/conf.json",
    "lint": "eslint app",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only dist",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only dist",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cross-fetch": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My firebase.json file

```js
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint"
    ],
    "source": "dist"
  }
}
```

Comment: As a first shot, I'd recommend trying `firebase deploy --only functions`. The behavior depends on how things are configured in your `firebase.json` file. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added the firebase.json file. I can't make sense of how I should tell firebase I would like to deploy from dist without having to duplicate my node_modules and my package.json into dist.

Comment: Ah, you'll definitely need the `package.json` in the folder that you tell Firebase to deploy. There's no way around that: the Firebase CLI pretty much goes to the directory you tell it to (so `dist` in your case) and uses the `package.json` to determine your dependencies, and what scripts to run.